# Change Subclipse Commit Behaviour

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

This may seem like a silly question, but it is something that drives me absolutely crazy!

I use the Subclipse plugin of Eclipse to check-in code for a project. When I go to commit changes, Subclipse prompts for a commit message (as expected). What happens is, I start typing my commit message, press `Shift` + `Enter`... and of course, it commits my changes, including my incomplete message.

Is there anyway to change this behaviour? Say, to have `Enter` commit the changes? I don't mind if there isn't an easy fix, so long as there *is* a fix with steps to follow.

Comment: Why are you pressing Shift+Enter? I use Subclipse all the time and I've never had a problem with an unintended commit the way you describe.

Comment: In many other applications, pressing `Enter` can cause the field to submit. `Shift` + `Enter` usually creates a new line without submitting anything.

Comment: I really hope somebody has an answer to this. This is extremely annoying and has littered my SVN base with half-typed commit messages. `shift` + `enter` should not submit the commit. It should enter a line-feed, as it is expected to do.

Comment: have you checked key shorcuts? window -> preferences -> general -> keys

Comment: @fmucar - I just looked and did not see anything that appeared to set this behavior.

Comment: This exact problem drives two of my fellow developers crazy! The problem is as described above: several other applications use shift-enter for newline and when you're going between the two it is very easy to make a commit when you didn't intend to. Is there a consensus on how much this feature irritates the community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(In the interests of assisting anyone with this problem...)

No, it does not look like this is possible as of Eclipse Indigo. The only way to change this behaviour seems to be making a code change in the plugin and recompiling yourself.